# Set new path android

Tags: android, path

This is a part of my code:

```
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);    
CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);     
mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);    
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/Video.mp4");    
mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000000); // Set max duration 60 sec.    
mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(500000000); // Set max file size 5M
```

The whole class record the video from live cam to sdcard. But as I always save it with the same path, a new video that I record, overwrites on the previous one. How can I change the path that each time it is saved with new name or in the way which videos do not overwrite on each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use hardcore string like `'/sdcard'` or `'/mnt/sdcard'` .

Always use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Use below function to get new name every time.

```
 private File getNextFileName() 
 {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Video_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4" );
    return file;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of video.mp4 get System.nanoTime() and insert it into the path.

```
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/" + System.nanoTime() + "_video.mp4");
```